# creating a customized Bing Map

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, bing-maps

I'm currently working on a project (Water Information System) and I really need to create a simple customized map for the software I'm currently working on.

The maps would only have info. about the communities around, water links and closest water purification chambers

How do i create a create a customized bing map where
 1. Map Admins can create and update the map (by adding new water chambers/ info)
 2. Users can easily view only the customized map.

I'm having problems doing that with the BING MAP SDK + Visual Studio 2010 + Silverlight.
Please any possible solution, hint or suggestion. Thanks

Comment: This is definitely sounds possible, but your question is vague and very general. I am doing something very similar using the same tools so I could probably help. What kind problems are having?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for help on this ...

I have done something similiar but instead of using the Silverlight BingMaps control, I've used the AJAX instead, and controlled it all via Javascript.

You'd want to have 2 screens for your project - one where the Admins can plot and drop their data (water chambers) and you save those to a database with their Geo coordinates.

the 2nd screen would be the end-users loading the map, and you would create another EntityCollection layer holding all of the data pulled from the database.

Here is a sample project I found that should provide you a template to get started
http://ajaxmapdataconnector.codeplex.com/